# iTextSharp - does not contain a definition for 'getInstance'

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, itext

I'm trying to generate a pdf from image with iTextSharp, but I'm getting the following errors: **iTextSharp.Image does not contain a definition for 'getInstance'** and 'iTextSharp.text.Document does not contain a definition for 'add' and 'iTextSharp.text.Document does not contain a definition for 'newPage' and iTextSharp.text.Image does not contain a definition for 'scalePercent'**

I have already add the iText Library (itextsharp, itextsharp.pdfa and itextshar.xtra). here is my code:

```
       private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "name.pdf";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width,
                                                panel1.ClientSize.Height))
            {
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, panel1.ClientRectangle);
                bitmap.Save("C:\\" + (nPaginasPDF + 1) + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }

            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(yourOutFile));
            doc.Open();

            for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < nPaginasPDF; iCnt++)
            {


                iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\" + (iCnt + 1) + ".bmp");
                image1.ScalePercent(23f);
                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(image1);
            }
            using (var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
            {
                doc.Save(Stream);
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both @Nenad and @MaxStoun are correct, you just need to adapt the Java conventions to .Net. Additionally, you'll also need to swap the Java `FileOutputStream` for the .Net `System.IO.FileStream` object.

**EDIT**

You have some "magic variables" in there that I need to work around. For instance, I'm not 100% sure what you're doing with your `for` loop so I just removed it for this sample. Also, I don't have write permissions to my `c:\` directory to I'm saving to the desktop. Otherwise, this code should hopefully get you on the correct path.

```
  //I don't know what you're doing with this variable so I'm just setting it to something
  int nPaginasPDF = 10;

  //I can't write to my C: drive so I'm saving to the desktop
  string saveFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

  //Set the default file name
  saveFileDialog1.FileName = "name.pdf";

  //If the user presses "OK"
  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      //Create a bitmap and save it to disk
      using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height)) {
          panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, panel1.ClientRectangle);
          //Path.Combine is a safer way to build file pathes
          bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(saveFolder, nPaginasPDF + ".bmp"), ImageFormat.Bmp);
      }

      //Create a new file stream instance with some locks for safety
      using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None)) {
          //Create our iTextSharp document
          using (var doc = new Document()) {
              //Bind a PdfWriter to the Document and FileStream
              using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                  //Open the document for writing
                  doc.Open();
                  //Get an instance of our image
                  iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.IO.Path.Combine(saveFolder, nPaginasPDF + ".bmp"));
                  //Sacle it
                  image1.ScalePercent(23f);
                  //Add a new page
                  doc.NewPage();
                  //Add our image to the document
                  doc.Add(image1);

                  //Close our document for writing
                  doc.Close();
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: pls, see my EDIT. What I need write in 'yourOutFile' ?

Comment: Do you mean why is the image smaller in the PDF then in your Panel? That's because of your code that says `image1.ScalePercent(23f);` Remove it if you don't want to scale the image.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iText documentation or books for Java, you need to adapt things a bit for .NET. In your example, since .NET implicit getters and setters for properties, this:

```
var instance = iTextSharp.Image.getInstance();
```

becomes this:

```
var instance = iTextSharp.Image.Instance;
```

Second issue: method names in Java are camel case, vs .NET pascal case, so this (camelCase):

```
image1.scalePercent(23f);
doc.newPage();
doc.add(image1);
```

becomes this (PascalCase):

```
image1.ScalePercent(23f);
doc.NewPage();
doc.Add(image1);
```

And so on. Just apply **.NET code naming conventions** instead of Java's.

Answer (score 1):

You'll upper first letter in method name (I just downloaded it from Nuget)

```
Image.getInstance(); => Image.GetInstance();    
doc.add(image1); => doc.Add(image1);
```

Comment: Thx, It works..but what I need write instead of 'yourOutFile'?  ´Document doc = new Document(); PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(yourOutFile));`